# How can we reset a service account password in the F5 CLI?

Tags: load-balancer, f5

How can we reset a service account password in F5 from the CLI? Is that even possible? If yes, can anyone please let me know the CLI commands?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

**Using tmsh to modify the system maintenance account passwords**

*Impact of procedure:* Performing the following procedure should not have a negative impact on your system.

Log in to the TMOS Shell (tmsh) by typing the following command:

```
tmsh
```

To modify the password for the root account, type the following command:
Note: If you need to modify the password for only the admin account, skip to step 5.

```
modify auth password root
```

When prompted, type the new root password.
When prompted, retype the new root password to confirm.
Note: If you need to modify the password for only the root account, skip the remaining steps.

To modify the password for the admin account, type the following command:

```
modify auth user admin prompt-for-password
```

When prompted, type the new admin password.
When prompted, retype the new admin password to confirm.
To save changes to the configuration files, type the following command:

```
save sys config
```

Exit tmsh by typing the following command:

```
quit
```

source: